# Web store: will customers come back to re-place orders?

Tags: e-commerce

Recently a bug in our web store caused the prices to be doubled at checkout. This lead to a drop in orders from about 25 to 2 over a period of 19 hours. We have lost quite some money over this. What I wonder is: is there any way to measure how many of those "dropped" customers will come back and re-place their orders?

Comment: In the absence of any information about your system, I do not consider this programming related.

Comment: I agree with Cerebus in that we probably need more information to provide an opinion. For example, you need to consider how loyal your customers are, how specialised your product is (and thus how easy is it for them to purchase elsewhere), etc

Answer (score 1):

If they logged in, their user details. If not, compare IP addresses from your server log, IPs which left without buying during the price doubling, to IPs in the next week, to get a rough idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would say if your product is good your customers will come back.  I would say now is a good time to start collecting some analytics on your site.  You won't have much to compare to but it would be a place to start.  To tell if your customers are coming back you could compare the purchase data from before the issue to after.  I would think you'd have some type of userid they would have to either log in with or enter when purchasing.  Our sites all require a username to login, we also offer a guest checkout which is just an email address but we could comparisons if we needed to.

Answer (score 0):

A non-programming solution is to offer customers who had the problem some kind of discount  or additional product if they finalise their order. This doesn't help you find out how many come back because you are changing the rules, but it will help you lose some of the lost money.

If you have a mailing list, mail out the special offer, else put it up on your website somewhere.

Ask them to fill in the details of the order again, if it matches a previous order in that time period offer them the special deal.